# Django SetUpTestData leads to database error with ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am trying to test a Django application using a test runner. I would like to set up the test data once to run across several different test classes, rather than setting up the same data in each test class. For that reason, I am using `setUpTestData()` rather than `setUp()`. The model includes a `ManyToManyField` to connect collaborators to articles. When I set up a class to test the models using `setUpTestData()`, I am able to save and retrieve objects from the `Collaborator` model and the `Article` model.

When I try to save the many-to-many relationship, however, I get an error that the table doesn't exist. How can I set up the test so that I can reuse these data, including the many-to-many relationship.

Here is my code:

```
from django.test import TestCase

from cv.settings import PUBLICATION_STATUS, STUDENT_LEVELS
from cv.models import Article, ArticleAuthorship, Collaborator

from tests.cvtest_data import PublicationTestCase

class ArticleTestCase(TestCase):
    """
    Run tests of Django-CV :class:`~cv.models.Article` model.
    """
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # Collaborator
        cls.col_einstein = Collaborator.objects.create(
            first_name="Albert", last_name="Einstein", email="ae@example.edu"
        )

        # Article
        cls.art_gravitation = Article.objects.create(
            title='On the Generalized Theory of Gravitation', short_title='Generalized Theory of Gravitation',
            slug='gen-theory-gravitation', pub_date='1950-04-01',
            status=PUBLICATION_STATUS['PUBLISHED_STATUS']
        )

        # Authorship: ManyToManyField
        cls.auth = ArticleAuthorship(
            article=cls.art_gravitation,
            collaborator=cls.col_einstein,
            display_order=1
            )
        cls.auth.save()

    def test_article_string(self):
        """Test that model returns short title of article as string"""
        a = Article.objects.get(
            short_title="Generalized Theory of Gravitation")
        self.assertEqual(a.__str__(), "Generalized Theory of Gravitation")
```

The error that I get is:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test suite for <class 'tests.test_article2.ArticleTestCase'>
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/webdev/djangoapps/django-vitae/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "~/webdev/djangoapps/django-vitae/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 296, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: main.cv_article__old
```

I have tried adding `super(ArticleTestCase, cls).setUpTestData()` and creating the relationship in the test functions which, it seems one should not do using `setUpTestData()`. But I did it as an experiment, and it threw the same error.

Comment: Which exact command do you use to run the tests?

Comment: `run_tests` from `django.test.utils.get_runner` in a runtests.py file that includes `coverage` reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue was not with my tests, but with an incompatibility between the way that older versions of Django roll back database transactions and the updated behavior of SQLite, as documented in [this bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29182) (I was using old code and wanted to run the tests before updating to newer versions). Updating Django to version 2.1.5 solved the error.